# How do parent link in Angular and then click on child link get other style

Tags: angular, styles, router, routerlinkactive

I need do parent link. I did, but sure it correct.
When I click routerLinkActive="router-class" , child and parent link can to get class "router-class",
but I when click on child link - parent link must change get class routerLinkActive="router-class-other-style" and if I send link with clicked link, style must to be how is, with
How it do?

```
<nav class="menu-container">
    <div class="container" >
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav" >
<a id="parent" routerLink="/" routerLinkActive="router-class"    >PARENT Router</a>
    <li id="menu"><a routerLink="/box" routerLinkActive="router-class">BoxComponent-CHILD</a></li>
    <li id="menu"><a routerLink="/pageone" routerLinkActive="router-class">Pageone-CHILD</a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

////////

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { BoxComponent } from './box/box.component';
import { PageoneComponent } from './pageone/pageone.component';
const appRoutes: Routes = [
{path: 'box', component: BoxComponent},
{path: 'pageone', component:PageoneComponent} 

];
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(
      appRoutes,
      { enableTracing: true }
    )
  ],
  exports: [
    RouterModule
  ]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P8p0Q.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

i cant clearly get your question but as per my understanding its about different style for parent and child

you can do that by using encapsulation in component

[view-encapsulation-document](https://angular.io/guide/view-encapsulation)